# Always null value passed from fragment to adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a recycler view on my home page which is showing some posts from my db. I'm passing data like `userID`, `username` etc., into the adapter but the profile picture URL is always null inside the adapter. If I try to print it inside the fragment it shows the correct value.

**My database structure:**

[image: Posts Node]

[image: Users Node]

**PostRecyclerAdapter:**

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<PostModel> postList;
    Context context;

    final private DatabaseReference postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
    final private DatabaseReference likeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("likes");
    final private DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    public PostRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<PostModel> postModelArrayList, Context context) {
        this.postList = postModelArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // check if post is liked or not
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // check if current post is liked from this user
                if (snapshot.child(holder.id).hasChild(user.getUid())) {
                    // post is liked form this user
                    holder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_filled);

                } else {
                    // post is not liked from this user
                    holder.like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thump_up_outline);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        // Get current post id set username, authorID, profile picture URL, likes and post image URL
        holder.id = postList.get(position).getId();
        holder.username.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
        holder.userID = postList.get(position).getAuthorID();
        holder.like_counter_tv.setText(postList.get(position).getLikes());

        Glide.with(context).load(postList.get(position).getImgUrl()).into(holder.postImg);

        // Load profile picture
        String profilePictureUrl = postList.get(position).getProfileImgUrl();
        
        // profilePictureUrl IS ALWAYS NULL
        if (profilePictureUrl != null) {
            if (!profilePictureUrl.equals("none")) {
                Glide.with(context).load(profilePictureUrl).into(holder.profileImage);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView container;
        String id;
        TextView username, like_counter_tv;
        ImageView postImg;
        ImageButton like_btn;
        CircleImageView profileImage;
        boolean isLiked = false;
        String userID;

        public void updateLikes(String postID, boolean isNotLiked) {
            postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    String currentLikesToString = snapshot.child(postID).child("likes").getValue().toString();
                    int currentLikesToInt = Integer.parseInt(currentLikesToString);

                    if (isNotLiked) {

                        int newCurrentLikes = currentLikesToInt + 1;
                        String newCurrentLikesToString = Integer.toString(newCurrentLikes);

                        // Update likes on Real-time DB
                        postRef.child(postID).child("likes").setValue(newCurrentLikesToString);

                        // update likes on TextView
                        like_counter_tv.setText(newCurrentLikesToString);

                    } else {

                        int newCurrentLikes = currentLikesToInt - 1;
                        String newCurrentLikesToString = Integer.toString(newCurrentLikes);

                        // Update likes on Real-time DB
                        postRef.child(postID).child("likes").setValue(newCurrentLikesToString);

                        // update likes on TextView
                        like_counter_tv.setText(newCurrentLikesToString);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            final ConstraintLayout sContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_container);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_container);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
            postImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            like_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            like_counter_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_counter);
            likeRef.keepSynced(true);

            profileImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);

                usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (snap.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(username.getText().toString())) {
                                UserProfileActivity.username = username.getText().toString();
                                UserProfileActivity.userID = snap.child("id").getValue().toString();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                context.startActivity(intent);
            });

            sContainer.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
                FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                PostOptionsDialog optionsDialog = new PostOptionsDialog();
                optionsDialog.setPostId(id);

                if (username.getText().toString().equals(user.getDisplayName())) {
                    optionsDialog.setAuthor(true);
                } else {
                    optionsDialog.setAuthor(false);
                }

                optionsDialog.show(manager, "options");

                return false;
            });

            like_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                // animate like button when clicked
                YoYo.with(Techniques.Shake)
                        .duration(500)
                        .repeat(0)
                        .playOn(like_btn);

                isLiked = true;

                likeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (isLiked) {
                            if (snapshot.child(id).hasChild(user.getUid())) {
                                // post is liked from this user, so user wants to unlike this post
                                like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thump_up_outline);
                                likeRef.child(id).child(user.getUid()).removeValue();
                                isLiked = false;
                                Toast.makeText(context, "You unliked this meme!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                // update likes to DB
                                updateLikes(id, false);

                            } else {
                                // post is not liked from ths user, so the user wants to like this post
                                like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_filled);
                                likeRef.child(id).child(user.getUid()).setValue("true");
                                Toast.makeText(context, "You liked this meme!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                // update likes to DB
                                updateLikes(id, true);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    }

}
```

**HomeFragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    LoadingDialog progressDialog;
    final DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
    final DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view);
        final ArrayList<PostModel> postModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        final RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter(postModelArrayList, getContext());
        final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        progressDialog = LoadingDialog.Companion.get(getActivity());

        progressDialog.show();

        postsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                progressDialog.hide();

                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    PostModel postModel = new PostModel();
                    postModel.setId(snap.child("id").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setImgUrl(snap.child("imgUrl").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setLikes(snap.child("likes").getValue(String.class));
                    postModel.setName(snap.child("name").getValue(String.class));

                    // find user id  and set profile picture by name
                    usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snap1 : snapshot1.getChildren()) {
                                if (snap1.child("name").getValue(String.class).equals(snap.child("name").getValue(String.class))) {
                                    postModel.setAuthorID(snap1.child("id").getValue(String.class));
                                    postModel.setProfileImgUrl(snap1.child("profileImgUrl").getValue(String.class));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    postModelArrayList.add(postModel);

                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You added same classes twice [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70003894/edit) your question .

Comment: @ADM Thanks, i edit my question

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Okay, i did it

Comment: Is the Author ID null as well? Something might be happening with your addValueEventListener from the usersRef (could be initialized later, so maybe calling recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after these values are added to the postModel would help?)